# Is it possible to use pre-defined variables as template expression variables for Azure Pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

lets say we have the yaml below.

```yaml
jobs:
- template: templates/jobs.yml 
  parameters:
     myBranch: ${{ variables.Build.SourceBranch }}
```

I notice we cannot compile the pre-defined variables as template expression variables but I didn't find any documentation about this in the this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

So, Is it possible to use pre-defined variables like `Build.SourceBranch` as template expression variables `${{ var }}` in Azure Pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is available but not for all variables.

[image]

You should check if variable is [available in the template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

And Build.SourceBranch is available

[image]

I tested this

```
trigger: none


jobs:
- template: build.yml 
  parameters:
     name: ${{ variables['Build.SourceBranch'] }}
```

and

```
parameters:
- name: name  # defaults for any parameters that aren't specified
  default: ''
jobs:
- job: Test
  steps:
  - script: echo '${{ parameters.name }}'
```

and I got

```
Generating script.
Script contents:
echo 'refs/heads/main'
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/a699d41a-2dd0-4109-89bb-33829fdf5180.sh
refs/heads/main
Finishing: CmdLine
```

Comment: um...`available in template` doesn't mean `available in template expression`, right?

Comment: My understanding of this was that you could use this in syntax `${{ }}`

Comment: Thanks. It turns out I use `${{ variables.Build.SourceBranch }}` instead of `${{ variables['Build.SourceBranch'] }}`. The previous one somehow doesn't work and display a empty string.

Comment: That's great. Could you mark my reply as answer if it solved your issue?